# Including --data-binary in Robot Framework request

Tags: python, curl, robotframework

I'm posting a image (.svg/.png) using Robot Framework (the tabular pythonic way) using the --data-binary flag to test a rest API.  The documentation suggests it accepts binary data, but not how to use --data-binary. See [robot request docs](https://bulkan.github.io/robotframework-requests)
The post in CURL looks like this:

```
curl -w "\n%{http_code}\n" -H "Content-Type: image/png" -u user:pass --data-binary "data=@~/someImage.png" -X POST "http://website/{id}"
```

The test case is formatted like so:

```
${result} =         Post        url=${ROOT}/website/{id}        data=${if-post-has-data}        headers=&{REQ_HEADER}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the contents of `${if-post-has-data}`? Have you tried using the `files` option? When you run the code in your question, what happens?

Comment: Hi Bryan, ${if-post-has-data} uses the encode method in python (base64),  I also tried robot's "Get Binary File" and passing it to data and I applied the same method and passed it into file= in the post and it also failed.  Is that what you you're asking?